# Reading data just written to a temp file

Tags: go, temporary-files

In Go, I am trying to write data to a temp file that I then turn around and read but have not been successful.  Below is a stripped down test program.  I have verified that the data are being written to the file by inspecting the temporary file.  So, at least I know that data are making it into the file.  I just am then unable to read it out.

Thank you for your help in advance

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", fmt.Sprintf("%s-", filepath.Base(os.Args[0])))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not create temporary file", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Created temp file: ", tmpFile.Name())
    //  defer os.Remove(tmpFile.Name())

    fmt.Println("Writing some data to the temp file")
    if _, err = tmpFile.WriteString("test data"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to write to temporary file", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("data should have been written")
    }

    fmt.Println("Trying to read the temp file now")
    s := bufio.NewScanner(tmpFile)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(s.Text())
    }
    err = s.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error reading temp file", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: After you write data file pointer is pointing to the end of the file. You have to seek to the beginning of the file to read what you wrote. Use tmpFile.Seek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ioutil.TempFile` creates a temp file and opens the file for reading and writing and returns the resulting `*os.File` (file descriptor). So when you're writing inside the file, the pointer is moved to that offset, i.e., it's currently at the end of the file.
But as your requirement is read from the file, you need to `Seek` back to the beginning or wherever desired offset using `*os.File.Seek` method. So, adding `tmpFile.Seek(0, 0)` will give you the desired behaviour.

Also, as a good practice, do not forget to close the file. Notice I've used `defer tmpFile.Close()` which closes the file before exiting.

Refer the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", fmt.Sprintf("%s-", filepath.Base(os.Args[0])))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not create temporary file", err)
    }
    defer tmpFile.Close()

    fmt.Println("Created temp file: ", tmpFile.Name())

    fmt.Println("Writing some data to the temp file")
    if _, err = tmpFile.WriteString("test data"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to write to temporary file", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Data should have been written")
    }

    fmt.Println("Trying to read the temp file now")

    // Seek the pointer to the beginning
    tmpFile.Seek(0, 0)
    s := bufio.NewScanner(tmpFile)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(s.Text())
    }
    if err = s.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error reading temp file", err)
    }
}
```

Update:
Comment from OP:

> Is the deferred close needed given that deleting the actual file is also deferred? If so, I imagine order of deferral would matter.

So, that's a nice question. So the basic rule of thumb would be to close the file and then remove. So, it might even be possible to delete first and later close it, but that is OS-dependent.

If you refer [C++'s doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove):

> If the file is currently open by the current or another process, the behavior of this function is implementation-defined (in particular, POSIX systems unlink the file name, although the file system space is not reclaimed even if this was the last hardlink to the file until the last running process closes the file, Windows does not allow the file to be deleted)

So, on Windows, that's a problem for sure if you try deleting it first without closing it.

So, as `defer`'s are stacked, so the order of execution would be

```
defer os.Remove(tmpFile.Name()) // Called 2nd
defer tmpFile.Close() // Called 1st
```

Comment: Thank you, @shmsr.  This worked perfectly.  Is the deferred close needed given that deleting the actual file is also deferred?  If so, I imagine order of deferral would matter.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped. And yes, I've updated my answer to clear your other doubts as well. Do let me know if it helps? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testdata/hello")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("File contents: %s", content)
```

according to the official golang docs.

Comment: He wants to do it the same program. I'd say this is not the correct answer w.r.t the question.